# Button preloader

Tags: javascript, html

Submit button onclick  calling a function.( onClick="mandatoryNotes()" ).
Its taking a bit time to loading. So added a preloader script. Now the pre loader is working but not calling the function.
Requesting help.
Thank you

```js
function mandatoryNotes()
{
   document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = ""; // to display
   return true;
}
var FirstLoading = true;
function RestoreSubmitButton()
{
   if( FirstLoading )
   {
      FirstLoading = false;
      return;
   }
   document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = ""; // to display
   document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}

//code for calling page

{
    var formvalue="invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM";
    validateInput(document.invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM);
    var queryString;
    if(checkValidation=="true"){
        //added by Nilanjana for 184932g
        //alert("entered");
        submitSpecialBidDetails(document.invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM);
        queryString = "&EUAM_SELECTED_FORM=" + formvalue;
        var legendURL = "/EUAM/ADRGateway?jadeAction=MANDATORY_NOTES_ACTION_HANDLER";
        var winData = 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,width=500,height=500';
        window.open("MandatoryNotes.jsp", "ADDVIEWNOTES",winData);
        window.close();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="em" id="formsubmitbutton">
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="buttonEm" onClick="mandatoryNotes()">
</div>
<div  id="buttonreplacement" style="margin-left:30px; padding-top:15px; display:none;">
<img src="loadingSubmit.gif"alt="loading...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using any asynchronous technique like AJAX with XHR request to post the form. As your request would take time to run the pre-loader should be shown until the result appears .
I would recommend you to see [JQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
You can write your submission code and start preloader before sending the request and stop it after the response is received.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submitbutton').on('click',function(){
    var mydata = [];      
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                    url: '',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: mydata ,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    beforeSend: mandatoryNotes()
                })
                    .done(function (ajax_data) {
                       
                      RestoreSubmitButton();
                    })
                    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                       
                       RestoreSubmitButton();
                    });
                return false;
            });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="em" id="formsubmitbutton">
  <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" id='submitbutton' class="buttonEm" onClick="mandatoryNotes()">
</div>
<div  id="buttonreplacement" style="margin-left:30px; padding-top:15px; display:none;">
  <img src="loadingSubmit.gif"alt="loading...">
</div>
```